# Add prefix in rest apis in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `server.js` file in which I have required `services.js` that further requires all the other API files

```
require('./web_services/services')(app);
```

I have two other files `Users.js` and `Events.js` that holds the actual apis. The `services.js` require both the files

```
var logger = require("../logger/logger");

module.exports = function (app) {
    require('./User/Users')(app,logger);
    require('./Event/Events')(app,logger);
    // in case of api error
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.send({ 'status': res.status, 'message': err });
        logger.error(err);
    }); 
}
```

Now I want to prefix `/users` before users apis and `events/` before event apis.
I have tried

```
app.use('/user/', require('./User/Users')(app));
```

**Users.js**

```
module.exports = function (app, logger) {
    // apis
};//exports
```

but this is not working? Am i missing something?

Comment: please share the file `Users.js` or tell us what it is actually exporting.?

Comment: @RaghavGarg, check updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can solve your problem by using [express routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

You can initialize router in `service.js` and then pass it around to enable routes and middleware in it and can define prefix in it in the service file as you were trying to do.

```
// service.js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();
...
app.use('/users', require('./User/Users')(router, logger));
app.use('/events', require('./Event/Events')(router, logger));
...
```

All the routes in this file will be prefixed by the `/users` because we have mentioned it in the service file.

```
// Users.js
module.exports = function (router, logger) {

    // middleware that is specific to this router
    router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
        logger('users middleware', req); // or however you are using your logger
        next();
    })

    // this route will be `/user/`    
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Users home page')
    })

    // this route will be `/users/about`
    router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
        res.send('About users')
    })

    return router;

};//exports
```

It's pretty straight forward I guess. You can refer [this](https://github.com/raghavgarg1257/nodejs-mysql-boilerplate) boilerplate, I made a while back ago using express and express router. Some naming convention is not good but yeah you can see how the router is defined and used in the boilerplate to enable route prefixing and middleware for specific routes.